# Batch extract arc files using command line tool(freearc)?

Tags: command-line, automatic-ref-counting, extract, archive

I have freearc's command line tool add-on installed and wish to run a batch extraction on a list of .arc files and each file has it's own password. I need these questions resolved:
1) What exe do I use?
2) How do I specify a password?
3) How do I specify destination directory?
4) How do I specify overwrite existing files?

Since I want the FULL command that would actually be typed into the CMD, I would like you to use the following information in your answer:
Name of archive: E:\GAMES\TEST.arc
Destination: E:\EXTRACTION\TEST
Password: test123

Thanks!

Comment: if you want to see that link here is a chached version: http://web-beta.archive.org/web/20120404084937/http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/313790/NET-Native-Multiple-File-Archive-Library

Comment: the cache does have some of his code, but it appears to be for creating an archive rather than extracting

Comment: If you have an 'unarc' program of some form you can look at calling it from vb.net. Just put all the required command line parameters in a Process.Start call.

Answer (score 0):

arc x -o+ file.arc //this for extra in path c:\users\name_user

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use arc.exe (usually it installed along with FreeArc)
2. you can specify a password with a flag -ptest123 or --password=test123
3. for destination directory use flag -dpe:\extraction\test or --diskpath=e:\extraction\test
4. to override -o+

arc x -o+ -ptest123 -dpE:\EXTRACTION\TEST E:\GAMES\TEST.arc

or

arc x --override=+ --password=test123 --diskpath=E:\EXTRACTION\TEST E:\GAMES\TEST.arc

If your password is wrong arc will interactively ask you to enter another one. To bypass this behavior you can add -p- after your password, e.g.

arc x -o+ -ptest123 -p- -dpE:\EXTRACTION\TEST E:\GAMES\TEST.arc

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
echo Abhijeet Dhikale
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo Extracting Archive - Please Wait
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Arc.exe x "D:Setup\Game\Data1.arc" -o+ -dp"D:\Games\Game Name2"

cls
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo Done;) Enjoy The Game!
pause >nul
```